# Using a custom init (with parameters) in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use a custom initializer (with passed parameters, for dependency injection) for a view controller that is initialized in prepareForSegue. I don't understand exactly how the view controller is initialized in prepareForSegue, so not sure the correct pattern for this.

Here is the prepareForSegue code in my view controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "FilterPopover" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! FilterViewController
        vc.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}
```

I would like to pass data into the FilterViewController when it is created, so that I can make the property a constant (let, not var), and do not have to use an implicit unwrapped optional. The view controller that has the above method has the data to pass into the FilterViewController custom init.

Is there a pattern for using a custom init for segue.destinationViewController so that I can pass parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time `prepareForSegue` is called the destination view controller is already initialized. This is done for you by the Storyboard system which will eventually call `initWithCoder:` on your view controller. You could initialize your `let` properties here.

If you want to use a custom initializer you would have to create the controller in code without using storyboards in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

To complete that Joris said, in that case, you can additionnaly use a .xib separated file for your ViewController

Comment: Thanks for the detail. In this case, I think it may be more straightforward for me to use implicitly unwrapped optionals.